# PYTHON: Why can't the on_release function from the keyboard module detect anything?

Tags: python, input, keyboard

I've been trying for hours to get this piece of code to work. The issue seems to be that on_release doesn't detect anything, unlike on_press which works perfectly fine. I've tried to read up on these functions in the documentation([https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.on_release_key](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)), however it doesn't provide much help. Would you be so kind to help me out? This is my first post on stackoverflow btw.

Here's the aforementioned code:

```
import keyboard
import time

def on_press(event):
    print(f"Pressed:  {event.name}")

def on_release(event):
    print(f"Released: {event.name}")

keyboard.on_press(on_press)
keyboard.on_release(on_release)

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

The code is expected to print out the name of the key, whenever one is pressed or release and whether it is released or pressed. The part that displays the pressed buttons works just fine, but the same can not be said about released buttons. Namely, the on_release function doesn't seem to get called, despite calling keyboard.on_release(on_release).

Comment: Your on_release works if you comment out->> # keyboard.on_press(on_press). So the on_press influences on_release. I don't know why. Maybe the you can find something in the source https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/keyboard/__init__.py#L505

Answer (score 2):

I've finally managed to find a solution! The issue was that you can't use two different hooks for some reason, so I solved it with one.

```
import time
from keyboard._keyboard_event import KEY_DOWN, KEY_UP

def on_action(event):
    if event.event_type == KEY_DOWN:
        on_press(event.name)

    elif event.event_type == KEY_UP:
        on_release(event.name)

def on_press(key):
    print(f"Pressed:  {key}")

def on_release(key):
    print(f"Released: {key}")

keyboard.hook(lambda e: on_action(e))

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Although very simple, it sure is a lifesaver. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this too

```
import time
from pynput import keyboard
def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False  
    if key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('h'):
        print("h key pressed")
def on_release(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False  
    if key == keyboard.KeyCode.from_char('h'):
        print("h key released")
listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press , on_release=on_release)
listener.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
```